# Installing WebServer on EC2 but get this error code : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

Tags: amazon-ec2, webserver, amazon-rds

I am working on a project to install and configure an e-commerce project on AWS EC2 and RDS.

I can access the website ( via the EC2 webserver public ip address ).

Once I am on the website, I tried to complete the webserver configuration.

However, I hit into this problem - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:

It says I cannot add the email address into the SQL RDS database. However I used another unique email address,the configuration has no response to the request.

Not sure where I can start troubleshooting as there's no proper troubleshooting guide and response message from the system.

Appreciate any help I can get.

Cheers

[image]

Tried using unique email address but the system has no message / error messages with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue that I have faced. It was because of some web application problem that I am unable to fully install the e-commerce applications on the web server.

I reinstall the web server and also the e-commerce application and this time, I did not face the same issue again.